# How do I split the background into 2 separate colors behind an image using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[How do I do this in bootstrap?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X1Nn.png)

I'm trying to achieve this. Thank you!
Below are my codes so far

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active mr-5">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-5">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/profile.jpg">
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: This is done with the `before` and `after` pseudo-classes.

Comment: please share your code, what are you trying to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You no need know bootstrap to do this, just only css with `before` and `after` pseudo-classes.

Example

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

div::before, div::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

div::before { top: 0; background-color: #e6ccff }

div::after { bottom: 0; background-color: #99ffd6 } 

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img alt="example" src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/5620d4d19c203bbdd9638b662263e45e/tumblr_pyn0cwSNl71y47v4mo1_1280.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.image_holder {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(red 0%, red 50%, yellow 50%, yellow 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image_holder">
  
</div>
```

I think with Bootstrap you can't do this.
But you can use [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()) like in example.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is a top div and a bottom div and position: relative on the image. The image is centered into the div and then moved up by half its height via position: relative;

Thanks to @Hải Bùi for the sekelton code that I then modified.

```css
.top {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #e6ccff
}


.bottom {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #99ffd6;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom">
  <img alt="example" src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/5620d4d19c203bbdd9638b662263e45e/tumblr_pyn0cwSNl71y47v4mo1_1280.jpg" />
</div>
```